# How to upload RAR file and Extract the contents from it using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a codeigniter project...

I have to upload Zip and RAR files which contains excel and image in it. After uploading I have to read the contents from Excel sheet and insert into the database and move the images to a folder.

I can able to Unzip and get the contents from Zip file but where as I am unable to Extract the contents from RAR file.

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: is the rar package installed? http://nz2.php.net/manual/en/book.rar.php

Comment: Yeah installed it.. Am getting this error Call to a member function extract() on boolean

Comment: show your code.

Answer (score 0):

<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
AllowOverride All
Options None
Require all granted

The `<Directory>` block you've provided is from an Apache configuration file and is related to the `cgi-bin` directory within your XAMPP installation. This particular block seems to be allowing all requests (`Require all granted`) to the `cgi-bin` directory and also enabling the use of `.htaccess` files (`AllowOverride All`).

If you are encountering a "403 Forbidden" error when trying to access an image in a different directory (not the `cgi-bin` directory), the issue might not be related to the configuration shown in the block you provided. The `cgi-bin` directory is typically used for handling CGI scripts and might not be directly relevant to serving images.

To troubleshoot the "403 Forbidden" error for the image, you'll need to focus on the directory that contains the image, as well as the related configuration directives for that directory.

Here's a basic example of how you could configure access to a directory containing images:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/your_project/writable/platedata/plateimage">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In this example, you should replace `"C:/xampp/htdocs/your_project/writable/platedata/plateimage"` with the actual path to the directory containing your images. The `Options` directive allows directory indexing and following symbolic links if needed. The `AllowOverride None` directive disables the use of `.htaccess` files within this directory.

Remember to restart your Apache server after making any changes to the configuration files for the changes to take effect.

If you're still facing issues after reviewing and adjusting the configuration for the directory containing your images, consider checking the error logs and using your browser's developer tools to gather more information about the "403 Forbidden" error. Additionally, consulting with experienced developers or server administrators can be helpful for resolving complex configuration issues.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541

Answer (score -1):

PHP ZipArchieve extension can be used to extract zip files. Allow this extension in php.ini if not enabled by default.

Create A Folder uploads in application Root Directory

```
function file_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'zip';
    $config['max_size']    = '';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('upload_form_view', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $file = $data['upload_data']['full_path'];
        chmod($file,0777);
        if ($zip->open($file) === TRUE) {
                $zip->extractTo('./uploads/');
                $zip->close();
                echo 'ok';
        } else {
                echo 'failed';
        }
        $this->load->view('upload_success_view', $data);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT :** Do checkout this library that handles all kind of archieve files.

https://github.com/wapmorgan/UnifiedArchive

Comment: by this we can upload zip file but not RAR

Comment: modified the answer. Please check the library.